# CItrix Netscaler Nitro API whether they are transnational?

Tags: netscaler

Like netconf, netscaler nitro API have transaction support ?

SIngle API can be executed and seems immediately succeed or fail. If succeed, adds configs to running config and saved config.

Answer (score 0):

NITRO APIs are synchronous. It will return after success or fail only.
If you want to do multiple operation in single NITRO call, use macroapi. You can have multiple operations payload.

```
http://<NSIP>/nitro/v1/config/macroapi
```